# What is this data visualization (cumulation of different samples over time on one axis) called?

Tags: data-visualization, python

[image: Grammys cumulatively won by different artists over time]

See: https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2017/02/12/arts/music/how-beyonce-could-make-grammy-history.html

Bonus question: is there a snappy way to make such a visualization (doesn't have to be interactive) using one of Python's visualization packages like `seaborn` or `bokeh`?

Comment: This appears to be a simple line plot, just with a lot of data and every line using the same formatting except for the one being highlighted by the story.

Comment: Plots like this are sometimes called [spaghetti plots](https://www.google.com/search?q=spaghetti+plot&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT7JTKr6XSAhVilFQKHSVMBfYQ7AkIfQ&biw=1685&bih=1023).